# MSVCs Implementation of std::put_time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, locale, standard-library

I am working with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, and was looking at using `std::put_time`, so I created the following example:

```
int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    std::locale::global( std::locale("en-GB") );

    std::cout << std::put_time( std::localtime( &t ), "%x" ) << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
06/25/2013
```

Which isn't the date format I would expect from the `en-GB` locale. I also tried:

```
std::cout.imbue( std::locale("en-GB") );
```

But again, with the same output. Is this what output I should be getting for this locale, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: That is definitely wrong.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Do you know if this has been filed in Microsoft's bug database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working as intended. `std::put_time` works off of the stream's locale, not the global locale. `cout` is created, and imbued with the current global locale, before `main` is entered. Subsequent change to global locale doesn't affect it. You need to `imbue()` it explicitly.

Comment: So why then does `std::cout.imbue( std::locale("en-GB") )` before using `std::put_time` yield the same result?

Comment: Likely because "en-GB" is not a locale identifier that MSVC's implementation of `std::locale` recognizes (note that the standard doesn't specify the form of this string). "English_Britain" works for me, in that the resulting output is in day/month/year format.